# Spacing in footnote bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, footnotes, line-spacing

I use the `mla-paper` package to write my papers. My supervisor has told me to cite the references in the footnote. So I have done this in the header:

```
\usepackage[style=mla,style=verbose]{biblatex}
```

This prints the bibliography in the foot note. If there are two bibliogrpahic entires on the foot note of a page, then it does single spacing. But if a large entry takes up second line then it uses double spacing. I have attached a screeshot below.  I don't want to have this doublespacing. Everthing in the footnote citations should be single spaced. How this can be achieved?

[image: Foot Note]

Comment: Are you doublespacing your document? If so, how?

Comment: Yes, I Do. That mla-paper package does it by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to create "doublespacing" of lines in a LaTeX document. You don't know which method you use. If you use the command

```
\usepackage[doublespacing,nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
```

in the document's preamble, doublespacing is turned off in footnotes, floats (figures and tables), and minipage environments, and vertical spacing around display-math environments is also done sensibly.